# Selenium Xpath combine

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

It seems there is something terribly wrong with the X-path. I am trying to concatenate the X-path inside loop but the result is an error message.
Please help me out of this

```
WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]//tr//table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[contains(@id,'fs')]/tbody")); 

            for (int i=1; i<numRows; i++) 
            {
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                    if (row != null){
                        for (int j=0; j<numCols; j++){
                            if (row.getCell(j) != null){
                                if(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue() != null) {

                                    if(j==0 && !details[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("XXX"))
                                    {
                                    WebElement style=driver.findElement(By.xpath(e+"/tr["+k+"]/td[1]/input"));
                                    style.sendKeys(details[i][j]);
                                    style.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
                                    ReusableMethods.expliwait(driver);
                                    }
```

The Below error message is displayed in Eclipse console
`org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (51c2231ca09b3dab440d7c6ebce322de)] -> xpath: //tr[2]//tr//table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[contains(@id,'fs')]/tbody`**]**`/tr[0]/td[1]/input`

I have marked the wrong expression in BOLD in the above result. I am not sure why "]" is being added while concatenating X-path

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match element with `XPath` like 
`//tr[2]//tr//table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[contains(@id,'fs')]/tbody` + `/tr["+k+"]/td[1]/input` you might need to use below syntax:

```
WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]//tr//table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[contains(@id,'fs')]/tbody"));
WebElement style=e.findElement(By.xpath("./tr["+k+"]/td[1]/input"));
```

Also I suggest you to avoid this kind of `XPath` and use [simple relative `XPath`](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) expressions instead

Comment: Relative `XPath` could be used without involving `id`. Or if you want to use dynamically changing `id` like `<tag id="constant_part_dynamic_part">`, you can try something like `//tag[contains(@id, "constant_part_")]`